# Seekbar issue in FFMPEG

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG for playing audio files. But, seeking file for some audio files are inaccurate.Means, song is playing out of total duration also. This issue is coming while seeking the audio file. If I play continuously without seek, then there is no issue. I have used below code:

```
 int stream_index = av_find_default_stream_index(fmt_ctx);
 int64_t target = av_rescale(seekValue, audio_st->time_base.den,
            audio_st->time_base.num);
 if (avformat_seek_file(fmt_ctx, stream_index, INT64_MIN, target, INT64_MAX,  
 AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME) < 0) {   
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "ERROR av_seek_frame");
    } else {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "SUCCEEDED av_seek_frame");
        avcodec_flush_buffers(fmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->codec);
    }
```

Any help?